# AWS Batch failover strategy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-batch

I am using `AWS batch` for executing jobs, I am calculating the initial memory to use by content size. About 90% of times its successful but 10% times it fails with `OutOfMemory error`.

So for next attempt for this failed jobs, I would like to increase the memory and submit the job again. I can not use AWS batch `Job Attempts` for this, I will need a different **FailOver Strategy**.

One way I can use is to have a lambda to check the job status every 1 hr and if its failed submit the job again with additional memory.

Are there any other better ways to have FailOver strategy for AWS Batch jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Good question; I dont know of any scheduler (LSF, SLURM, AWS Batch) which supports this as it's IMHO not really what a scheduler should do - more the engine which executes your workflow ( think nextflow / ehive );

You can monitor your container status with AWS 'containerInsights' - see

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-metrics-ECS.html

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Supported Platforms > Currently, Container Insights isn't supported in AWS Batch.